# XDebug Breaks at line without breakpoint

Tags: php, xdebug

I'm currently using [php-debugger](https://github.com/gwomacks/php-debug) for Atom to debug a php project. For some reason, every time I run into `$character[$csv[0][$i]] = $a[$i];` in the below code, the debugger pauses.

```
$file = KRequest::get('files.file', 'raw');

if(!$file) {
    throw new LibBaseControllerExceptionBadRequest('File is missing');
    return;
}

$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file($file['tmp_name']));
array_walk($csv, function(&$a) use ($csv) {
    $count = count($csv[0]);
    $character = array();

    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {            
        $character[$csv[0][$i]] = $a[$i];
    }

    $a = $character;
});
array_shift($csv);
```

I did originally have a breakpoint within the `for` loop, but after some edits, that line was removed.

I've tried clearing all the breakpoints, upgrading Atom and upgrading the php-debugger package to no avail. My only thought is that the breakpoint is still saved someplace and stuck there or that that line of code is trigger some kind of notice that's not being logged to the php_error.log.

Any advice would be appreciated cause this is preventing me from debugging down the line. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an error that's cause XDebug to pause. I was trying to get values from the array for indexes that didn't exist. This must've caused some kind of error that wasn't being output or logged.